# Refactoring clojure `defn` to `fn` causes ClassCastException

Tags: clojure, refactoring, anonymous-function

I'm working on [4clojure's Prime Numbers
kata](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/67). I have solution that works perfectly
(if inefficiently) on my local machine, but it relies on `defn` which is
forbidden on 4clojure.

```
(defn factors [n]
  (->> n
       range
       (map inc)
       (filter #(zero? (mod n %)))))

(defn prime? [n]
  (->> (factors n)
       (count)
       (= 2)))

(defn n-primes [n]
  (->> (range)
       (filter prime?)
       (take n)))
```

I tried to refactor it to use only anonymous functions, but it blows up.

```
(fn x-primes [count]
  (let [x-factors (fn factors [n] (->> n range (map inc) (filter #(zero? (mod n %)))))
         x-prime? (fn [n] (->> (x-factors n) (count) (= 2)))]
        (->> (range)
             (filter x-prime?)
             (take count))))
```

Throwing the following error (when run both locally and with 4clojure's editor)

> ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn

What have I done wrong in refactoring the code?

On an aside, why do you suppose 4clojure bans `def` and `defn`?

Comment: Where specifically?

Comment: And how are you running it?

Comment: Cider when running locally. I was evaluating the s-exp from my editor (albeit with fn changed to defn), then invoking it by: `(x-primes 5)` in cider.

Comment: I should note though that wrapping your code in `fn`s while doing 4Clojure is probably unnecessary. You might as well just enter code snippets to be run.

Comment: BTW: you can use `letfn` to `let` functions - I refactored your code [here](https://repl.it/G3XQ/1) using `letfn`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're shadowing the `count` function with your parameter name. `(count some-num)` is throwing an error because in this scope, `count` is a number, not a function.

Change your parameter name from `count` to something else.

---

Also, in 4Clojure's help page, there's the following line:

> Some operations are prohibited for security reasons. For instance, you will not be able to use "def" or switch namespaces.

Since `defn` is just a `def` wrapping macro, it makes sense that it's also prohibited. How that would lead to a security problem though is beyond me.